# XCTest for test setter in model object

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xctest

I have a model object with computed variables. now i want to test setter of the variable. i wrote a test case and it gives the following error

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nil") is not equal to ("Optional("example@gmail.com")") -

bellow i have mentioned the test case which i wrote

```
func testNetworkModelObjectSet() {

    let testObject = ["network": ["first_name": "Dimuth", "last_name": "Lasantha", "business_email": "testemail@gmail.com", "currency": "USD", "language": "en-us", "category": "individual"]]

    let network = HVConnection(data: testObject)

    network.business_email = "example@gmail.com"

    XCTAssertEqual(network.business_email, "example@gmail.com")
}
```

here i have mentioned the related model object variable

```
class HVConnection: NSObject {

    //private var _data: NSMutableDictionary
    private var _data: NSMutableDictionary

    // MARK:- Init

    init(data: NSDictionary)
    {
        _data = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: data)
    }

    var business_email: String? {

        get {
            if let businessemailObject = _data.objectForKey("network")?.objectForKey("business_email") {
                return (businessemailObject as! String)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        set {
            _data = ["business_email": newValue!]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `XCTAssertEqualObjects` for object, `XCTAssertEqual` is for primitive types like, `int`, `char`, `double`, etc..

Comment: @rckoenes Swift's `XCTest` doesn't have `XCTAssertEqualObjects`.

Comment: @Cristik you are right, switching to much between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading from `_data["network"]["business_email"]`, but writing to `_data["business_email"]`. You should either update the getter, or the setter, depending on specifications.

As a side note, you can rewrite the getter in a more shorter/readable manner:

```
get {
    return _data["network"]?["business_email"] as? String
}
```

The [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) feature of Swift makes it very easy to check for nil in chain of method calls.

Also note that the setter will crash the app if a `nil` value is passed, as the forced unwrap crashes when trying to unwrap nils.

Answer (score 0):

by setting `network.business_email = "example@gmail.com"` you are overriding the content of `_data` with `["business_email": newValue!]`.

This will cause the getter to return `nil` since it will enter the `else` case because `_data.objectForKey("network")` is `nil`. Hence, the behaviour is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the setter as follows

```
set {
        _data = ["network":["business_email": newValue!]]
    }
```

Now the test case passed

Comment: Did one of the answers posted here helped you reach this solution?